# How to get the name of the instance disposed by using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, xunit

I am building some integration tests for my database stored procedures.
I have setup an xUnit project and implemented Fixture pattern. To show you:

```
public class MyTableTest : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{

    public MyTableTest()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
    }
}
```

This **DatabaseFixture** is something that will be shared among all of my test classes. Why? Because I want some common logic happening at the end of every test, such as cleanup.

Point is that I need to know which table to clean, which in my example would be **MyTable**. Such information I would retrieve by using reflection when the Dispose method will run against the instance of **MyTableTest** being disposed . How can I achieve this? Is it even possible (and correct) trying to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect to get `MyTable` out of any thing posted? The only place that appears is in `MyTableTest`, so are you planning on doing string manipulation against the test class' name? That seems fragile.

Comment: @KennethK. yeah that was the plan.. I agree with you though that it's fragile. Am I trying to complicate things here? I thought about using the Fixture offered by xUnit to avoid in a nice way repetition of code. When the instance gets disposed then the Dispose in Fixture would get called automatically by every test getting disposed.

Comment: Why not make `DatabaseFixture` generic, and then the generic type can be the database class you want to clean up?

Comment: @KennethK. and then from the database class I still need to retrieve the name of the table to clean, which means still string work. Or maybe you have something else in mind? could you maybe show me a solution?

Comment: IMHO for auto-cleanup, wrap your entire test in a transaction and roll it back. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases#maintaining-database-state

Comment: @JeremyLakeman not really because maybe in the same test I make multiple calls to the database that rely on the committment of each other, no? For example in the same test I write something in the db and then I want to read and check it out. If I don't commit the write, the read won't work, right?

Comment: If your database doesn't support nested transactions, then fake that. If you are using the same context, reading back will work just fine.

Comment: You write "Because I want some common logic happening at the end of every test,", but class fixtures are not disposed after each test, only after all tests in the class have been run. So if you just need to run something after each test, you could just derive from a common base class and implement the shared dispose method there.

Comment: The posted solutions will probably work but in my opinion your data model just isn't really correct.Your `DatabaseFixure` should have generics. So it looks like this `class MyTableTest : DatabaseFixure<MyTableTest>`. `MyTableTest` should then implement an interface `IDatabaseWriter` which defines a method `IEnumerable<String> GetTableNames()`

`DatabaseFixure` also has in it's generics definition `T where T : ITableNameProvider`. In the dispose method of `DatabaseFixure` you simply call `GetTableNames()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom attributes to attach any arbitrary data to your derived Fixture class.

For example

1. you can create a `TableNameAttribute` like this:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class TableNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public TableNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    } 
}
```

2. you can apply this attribute to your derived fixture class:

```cs
[TableName("MyTable")]
public class MyTableFixture : DatabaseFixture { }
```

3. you can use that fixture class inside your test

```cs
public class MyTableTest : IClassFixture<MyTableFixture>
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Finally this is how you can retrieve the `Name` from the `Dispose` method:

```cs
public abstract class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var attribute = this.GetType().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TableNameAttribute));
        if (attribute is TableNameAttribute tableNameAttr)
            Console.WriteLine(tableNameAttr.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: this one doesn't work unfortunately.. have you tried?

Comment: @Tarta I've tried it via this code: `var test = new MyTableTest(); test.Dispose();`. It did print `MyTable` on console. Could you please elaborate what does it mean: *this one doesn't work*?

Comment: When I debug the Dispose in the  IClassFixture, it doesn't retrieve any custom attributes. And if I check the type of the instance being disposed, it's of type DatabaseFixture , meaning the base class, meaning the one without attribute. That's why it cannot retrieve any custom attributes

Comment: @Tarta `this` always point to the derived class. So, `this.GetType()` should give us back `MyTableTest`. I'll try my code with xunit tests.

Comment: @Tarta Ohh okay, I've found where is the problem. I try to fix it.

Comment: @Tarta I've posted the fixed version, please check it again.

Comment: Thanks for posting this first of all ! Your previous version (the one that didn't work) is what in practice I was trying at the beginning: giving a property to my class (in your case it was an attribute, in my case a property) that we could retrieve at Dispose through reflection. I don't really understand why your version works now to be honest. In practice you created one more layer on top of the testing class. That layer is just an empty class! Maybe not great for what I am looking for. Nothing to say about your code eh!! I absolutely thank you and appreciate your time spent in this!

Comment: But why the need of creating that extra layer? possible that there is no way to give that attribute directly to the Test class and retrieve it at the Dispose?

Comment: @Tarta The fixture's creation and disposal (so its lifecycle) is handled by xunit. That means xunit will create a `DatabaseFixture` class in case of  `IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>`, which won't have any connection to the `MyTableTest` from the Call Stack perspective. So, I had to introduce an intermediate layer which holds the required data. `MyTableFixure` will be created and disposed by xunit and its base class can contain the common / shared logic. I agree that is approach seems a bit cumbersome but it separates the concerns from each other and the responsibilities are cleanly separated.

Comment: @PeterCsala why not using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute` ?

Comment: @iSR5 Yes, that can be a viable alternative. If the OP needs no other data than the TableName then yes the built-in attribute is sufficient.

Comment: this is not the cleanest solution, the one from @Reza most likely is but your solution explains me how to make it work with reflection which is what I was trying from the beginning. I vote yours because (besides working) you have put quite some efforts in helping me and I appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tarta I appreciate your honesty.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `TableName` property in the `DatabaseFixture` class. Then receive an instance of the class in constructor of your test classes and set that `TableName` property. Later you can use it in dispose to do some cleanup.

```
public class MyTableTest : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture databaseFixture;
    public MyTableTest(DatabaseFixture databaseFixture)
    {
        this.databaseFixture = databaseFixture;
        databaseFixture.TableName = "MyTable";
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
    }
}
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    //...

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    //...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Cleanup based on TableName
    }
}
```

To learn more about sharing context in xUnit, take a look at:

- [Shared Context between Tests](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context)
- [Comparing xUnit.net to other frameworks](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible (and correct) trying to achieve this?

No. Reflection cannot tell type `T` in what context `T` is used; reflection only sees `T`'s declaration.
More specific to your situation, reflection cannot tell type `DatabaseFixture` that it is being used as a type parameter of generic interface `IClassFixture` in the declaration of `MyTableTest`. In other words, for this set of declarations,

```cs
class A { }
class B <T> {  }
class C : B<A> { }
```

`A` cannot reflectively determine that it is used in `C`'s declaration, but `C` can know about its usage of `A`:

```cs
typeof(C)
    .BaseType // B
    .GetGenericArguments()[0] // A
```

> How can I achieve this?

Depending on how you are using `DatabaseFixture`, you could get the calling test class using the `StackTrace` (if you are really bent on using reflection). Here is a simple example:

```cs
    public class DisposableObject : System.IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            var stack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();

            // This will log the name of the class that instantiated and disposed this. 
            System.Console.WriteLine(stack.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
            return;
        }
    }
```

If your `DatabaseFixture` is not called directly from your test class, you will either have to know the offset to pass to `GetFrame(int)`, or you will need to search each frame until you find the first `DeclaringType` that matches your requirements (e.g., `BaseType` is `IClassFixture` with Generic Argument `DatabaseFixture`), something like this:

```
System.Type testClassType = new StackTrace()
    .GetFrames()
    .Where(f =>
    {
        System.Type baseType = f.GetMethod().DeclaringType.BaseType;
        return typeof(IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>).IsAssignableFrom(baseType);
    })
    .FirstOrDefault() // First matching result (assuming you found any)
    ?.GetMethod() // Get the reflected Method
    .DeclaringType; // Get the type (e.g. class) that declares this method.
string tableName = testClassType.Name.Replace("Test", "");
```

Otherwise, you will need to set the table name manually, as suggested by [Reza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128761/6789816) and [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66152240/6789816).